# Will prettify cause conflicts in my git merges?

Tags: git, git-merge, pretty-print, merge-conflict-resolution, prettify

I've been introduced to a PHP / HTML codebase that is not consistently indented. I would like to run a "pretty code" or "prettify" on the code, but I am concerned that this will cause conflicts on some merges.

Any advice for accomplishing this or should prettify be avoided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this may cause merge conflicts.  I'd say your best bet is to coordinate such move with other developers so that as many branches as possible get merged before formatting code.